# Would you capitalize an awarded title like "hottest designer of the year"?

Tags: capitalization, titles

The sentence is,

> Randi proved herself to be worthy of the title of hottest designer of the year with her gorgeous designs.

Edit: If so, I can't help but feel that single quotation marks are indicated.
Randi proved herself to be worthy of the title of 'Hottest Designer of the Year' with her gorgeous designs.
Is this instinct correct?

Comment: Titles are capitalised.

Comment: You have a choice if you opt for << Randi proved herself to fully justify the claim to be  the hottest designer of the year with her gorgeous designs. >> But not with inescapable  titles